# Accessing a variable in a data frame by columns number in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, testing

I have a data frame as "df" and 41 variables `var1` to `var41`. If I write this command

```
pcdtest(plm(var1~ 1 , data = df, model = "pooling"))[[1]]
```

I can see the test value. But I need to apply this test 41 times. I want to access variable by column number which is "**df[1]"** for "**var1**" and "**df[41]**" for "**var41**"

```
pcdtest(plm(df[1]~ 1 , data = dfp, model = "pooling"))[[1]]
```

But it fails. Could you please help me to do this? I will have result in for loop. And I will calculate the descriptive statistics for all the results. But it is very difficult to do test for each variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can easily adapt the following code to your data. Since you didn't provide any of your data, I used data that comes with the plm package.

```
library(plm) # for pcdtest

# example data from plm package
data("Cigar" , package = "plm")
Cigar[ , "fact1"] <- c(0,1)
Cigar[ , "fact2"] <- c(1,0)
Cigar.p <- pdata.frame(Cigar)

# example for one column
p_model <- plm(formula = pop~1, data = Cigar.p, model = "pooling")
pcdtest(p_model)[[1]]

# run through multiple models
l_plm_models <- list() # store plm models in this list
l_tests <- list() # store testresults in this list

for(i in 3:ncol(Cigar.p)){ # start in the third column, since the first two are state and year 
  fmla <- as.formula(paste(names(Cigar.p)[i], '~ 1', sep = ""))
  l_plm_models[[i]] <- plm(formula = as.formula(paste0(colnames(Cigar.p)[i], "~ 1", sep = "")),
                           data = Cigar.p,
                           model = "pooling")
  l_tests[[i]] <- pcdtest(l_plm_models[[i]])[[1]]
}

testresult <- data.frame("z" = unlist(l_tests), row.names = (colnames(Cigar.p[3:11])))
> testresult
              z
price 175.36476
pop   130.45774
pop16 155.29092
cpi   176.21010
ndi   175.51938
sales  99.02973
pimin 175.74600
fact1 176.21010
fact2 176.21010

# example for cipstest
matrix_results <- matrix(NA, nrow = 11, ncol = 2) # use 41 here for your df
l_ctest <- list()

for(i in 3:ncol(Cigar.p)){
  l_ctest[[i]] <- cipstest(Cigar.p[, i], lags = 4, type = 'none', model = 'cmg', truncated = F)
  matrix_results[i, 1] <- as.numeric(l_ctest[[i]][1])
  matrix_results[i, 2] <- as.numeric(l_ctest[[i]][7])
}

res <- data.frame(matrix_results)
names(res) <- c('cips-statistic', 'p-value')
print(res)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will convert this code for my dataset.

Comment: Your code worked very well. But i want to encode your code for cipstest(
  dfp$roa,
  lags = 4,
  type = c("trend", "drift", "none"),"
  model = c("cmg", "mg", "dmg"),
  truncated = FALSE)
I wrote code as :
for (i in 1 : (ncol(dfp)-4)) {
  l_cipstest[[i]] <- formula = as.formula(paste0("dfp$", (colnames(dfp)[i+4]), sep="")), lags = 4, type = c("trend", "drift", "none"), model = c("cmg", "mg", "dmg"), truncated = FALSE))
  cip_sonuc()[c(i:i), c(1, 2)] <-c((cipstest(l_cipstest[[i]], test)[[1]]),
                                (cipstest(l_cipstest[[i]], test)[[5]]))
bu it doest work.

Comment: Ok, but that's a different question from the one posted above. Could you provide part of your data using `dput()` and include your current code in the question?

Comment: The same dataset and the same dataframe. I want to run cipstest and its all arguments is like that= cipstest( dfp$roa, lags = 4, type = c("trend", "drift", "none")," model = c("cmg", "mg", "dmg"), truncated = FALSE)    i want to save [[1]] and [[7]] in a new matrix. i have again 41 variables. I will create results = matrix(0, nrow = 41, ncos = 2). the data frame name is dfp. i want to run this test for 41 times and get the results of first and seventh indices values to save results matrix. Thank you so much. You are very helpful.

Comment: I added the cips-test, but in my example several p-values are the same (equal to 0.1). You'll have to check if it works for your data.

Comment: It worked perfect! thank you so much. You are really helpful.

Comment: thank you, if you think my answer was helpful, you can select it to be the one that answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `as.formula()`, for example:

```
results <- list()
for (i in 1:41){
  varName <- paste0('var',i)
  frml <- paste0(varName, ' ~ 1')
  results[[i]] <- 
    pcdtest(plm(as.formula(frml) , data = dfp, model = "pooling"))[[1]]
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will give feedback and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reformulate` to create the formula and apply the code for 41 times using `lapply` :

```
var <- paste0('var', 1:41)

result <- lapply(var, function(x) pcdtest(plm(reformulate('1', x), 
                                    data = df, model = "pooling"))[[1]])
```